# Is the phrase 'maybe because' grammatical?

Tags: grammar

For example:

'As for TikTok, maybe because it has higher engagement rate..."

'...I have a feeling he's angry with me, and it's maybe because of what I said to Linda."

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to say more about why this construction concerns you. Questions asking "are this right" are not [on-topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) unless they point to a specific concern. You'll get better answers that way; maybe we can explain *why* the construction is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is grammatical. The meaning is the same as "perhaps because" (which I would prefer).

The writer is suggesting but not insisting on a reason for something.

Comment: "and it may be because of what I said to Linda" is also possible, and perhaps a little more formal.

Comment: Or "I have a feeling he's angry with me, and maybe it's because of what I said to Linda." [After "me", almost _any_ punctuation mark will do.]